# How can I get the maximum bid value in a blind auction?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a blind auction as part of my class, and I'm trying to get the max value.
Here is the code, I tried to use the max() function but I get this error:

```
File "Day_9_Blind_Auction.py", line 30, in <module>print(max(data))TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

```
import os

data = [
    
    
    
    ]
while True:
    name = input("What is your name?: ")
    bid = input("What is your bid: $")

    other_user = input("Are there any other bidders? Type Yes or No.\n")
    
    if other_user in ['yes', 'Yes']:
        os.system('cls')
 
    def new_user(name, bid):
        brandnew_user = {
            name: bid
            
            },
        
        data.append(brandnew_user)
        
    new_user(name, bid)

    
    
    if other_user in ['no', 'No']:
        print(max(data))
        break
```

I tried to remove the max() and it prints the output totally fine.  But then I need to get the max value, which is I don't know how to do it.

this is the output if I removed the max() function:

```
[({'George': '87'},), ({'Josh': '74'},), ({'Eduardo': '89'},)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to apply the max() function to a list of dictionaries.   The error message is telling you that you haven't specified how to tell when one dictionary is "greater than" another.

It is possible to add a definition for the '>' operator that would allow it to compare dictionaries, but it's probably better if you rethink the data structures you're using. A list of dictionaries, with only one key/value pair per dictionary, is kind of an awkward construction. Why not use one list for the names, another list for the bids, then use max() and indexof() to find the largest bid and get the corresponding name from the other list?